# Power Bi does not connect with MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, powerbi

I am trying to connect PowerBI desktop form with MySQL database on localhost. When I enter credential and try to connect I always get following popup box.

[image]

I don't know where should I look for error log in PowerBI

Comment: Try getting the latest version of Power BI. I can tell from your screen shot that isn't the latest build.

Answer (score 0):

Seems someone encountered the same problem as you did.

First result in Google: http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Power-BI-Desktop-error-when-connecting-to-local-MySQL/td-p/2724